# Generate DB2 Explain Plan from Remote Call

Tags: db2, sql-execution-plan, explain

I'm familiar with Oracle more so than DB2, I have a piece of JavaScript code that makes an Oracle (SQL) call that returns an explain plan, essentially a remote statement execution. From what I've read DB2 looks to be a little different in that there is a command line utility to generate the plan.

Is there a way to generate an explain plan via a remote call in the same way an SQL statement is prepared and executed?

Update:
I'm working in a hosted setup where to be honest I don't even know the version or platform for db2, I'm not sure if this will help but for Oracle we do this:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
stmt.execute("explain plan for "+sql); 
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from table(dbms_xplan.display())");
```

This (in rs) gives me a textual explain plan that includes the cost of the query, I'm looking to do the same for a db2 database where I assume this syntax isn't going to work.

Comment: Answer can depend on which operating-system type your DB2-server runs on ( Windows/Linux/Unix,  i-Series,  Z/OS ) , and the version/fixpack of the DB2-server product.  Please edit your post to add that information.

Comment: I'm working in a hosted setup where to be honest I don't even know the version or platform for db2, I'm not sure if this will help but for Oracle we do this:

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
 stmt.execute("explain plan for "+sql);
 rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from table(dbms_xplan.display())");  

This (in rs) gives me a textual explain plan that includes the cost of the query, I'm looking to do the same for a db2 database where I assume this syntax isn't going to work.

Comment: Post output of `select versionnumber, version_timestamp, versionbuildlevel from sysibm.sysversions`  . IBM  does not supply dbms_xplan module.   You could write a stored procedure (e.g in java) that runs db2expln or db2exfmt and returns their output as a result-set.  That's not pretty. Another option is to directly parse the EXPLAIN tables (into which Db2 writes the results of `explan plan for` but you would need to be an expert.  People use GUI tools to view access plans, e.g IBM Data Studio, or dbvisualiser etc.

Comment: See: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/db2/getting-an-execution-plan